# Trailing icon over an image on title Expansion Title Flutter

Tags: flutter

Below is the code, for the ExpansionTile. In the title, I'm calling the CurrentNoti which displays an image and displays those named arguments over an image. What I want is that the trailing arrow dropdown has to be over an image. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Look at the image, I want the drop-down over an image.

```
ExpansionTile(
   title: CurrentNoti(
          date: DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(
                     DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(
                         docs?[index]['date'].microsecondsSinceEpoch,
                     ),
                ),
          location: docs?[index]['location'],
         ),
   children: [
       Text("Some description here"),
   ],
);
```

Comment: can you add an image that you want to archive

Comment: I have uploaded the image, please look at that. @YeasinSheikh

Comment: can you share full widget for this card. i'll use stack for this

Comment: The complete code for the widget?

Comment: yes, im posting a sample here

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this property to expansion tile

```
trailing: Container(
        height: 40,
        decoration:BoxDecoration(
          image:DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532454-e138e28a63f4?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60'),
            fit:BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
      )
```

modify the constraints as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
demo widget:

```
class CardBodyStack extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardBodyStack({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 600,
      height: 200,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: [
            ///* background
            Image.asset(
              "assets/ocen.jpg",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),

            Positioned(
              bottom: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
              left: constraints.maxHeight * .1,

              /// you can use separate Possitioned here
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Date time here"),
                  Text(
                    "Blood Drive at DSU".toUpperCase(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 33,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            ///* place button BottomLevel of stack

            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: "VV 0",
                onChanged: (value) {},
                items: List.generate(
                  4,
                  (index) => DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text("item $index"),
                    value: "VV $index",
                  ),
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
              right: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("share");
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.share,
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your effort. But this is not what I wanted. Have you used ExpansionTile? If so, then there is a default down arrow trailing button, if we click it, it will show more description about a list item. If you look at the image I uploaded above, the down arrow is on the right. I want the image to consume the full width and the trailing down arrow to be over an image.

Comment: oh got it, in that case we can use stack and place image as background.  im checking it